# Wrong Date Conversation (ndY to Y-m-d H:i:s)

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

My code is returning the wrong date conversation

```
<?php
$date = '8312015';
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('ndY', $date);
$convertedDate = $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $convertedDate;
```

Returns

```
0021-11-12 17:04:56
```

Expects:

```
2015-08-31 00:00:00
```

Questions:

1. Why PHP can't convert **`ndY`** to **`Y-m-d H:i:s`**
2. Why PHP append the current hours, instead of **`00:00:00`**

Note: I tried with `date()`, `date_create`, `date_format` and I got same results (wrong date)

Comment: That date format is ambiguous. Use one that is easier to parse. And unless specified PHP will return current hours. See the manual for `DateTime::createFromFormat()` for how to do it.

Comment: What date would `1152015` supposedly be – is it Jan 15th or Nov 5th? Exactly – no one could say.

Comment: Should return Jan 15

Comment: Sorry i just update the question ndY is the format from the input

Comment: Looks like 83rd month twelfth day of year 015 to me. which if you take 83 months into 0015 you end up in Nov of 0021, so in a way its exactly right! If instead you used $date= '08312015', you might get better results. (?)

Comment: @Octopus unfortunately i don't have control of the  input.  The program receive it in that format. the date format is ndY(n=8 d=31 Y=2015)

Comment: @Lea, so clean it. if its less than 8 chars put a '0' at the front. easy!

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to convert this format without "hacking" it. Maybe the answer is you can't do that. I hate to hack code.

Comment: Sanitizing the input is not necessarily hacking it.

Comment: So you are saying that it is impossible to convert ndY to Y-m-d H:i:s (straight conversation)

Comment: If you neither normalize the input nor want to do it in your code, then yes it's impossible. The old saying is: garbage in -- garbage out.

Comment: @LeaTano: Honestly, your "straight conversation" requirement makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close! `m` is actually :

> Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros     01 through 12

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

So, that means it expects it to be 2 characters, not one. If you do

```
$date = '08312015';
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('ndY', $date);
```

It works how you want it to

When you do

```
$date = '8312015';
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('ndY', $date);
```

You get month=83, day=12, year=015

83 months is 6 years+ 11 months
so, `015+6=21` years +11 months=november 11th of year 21, ie (`0021-11-12`), which matches the output

**Edit**: so apparantly you meant `n` not `m`, the problem being that you have no delimiter between date parts, so, as has been said, it is ambiguous as to whether the month should be 8 or 83...

**Edit Again** My "answer" just explained the problem I guess without showing how to fix it, so...

If the fields are not delimited either by a delimiting character (like a `-`) or by field length (ie, how `m` is *always* 2 characters) then the conversion is ambiguous. Given that apparantly php considers 83 a valid month, and that a month formatted as `n` may have 1 or more digits, when php sees 83, it really can't know if you mean "8th month and then something starting with a 3" or "the 83rd month".

So, what you need to do is disambiguate the delimiting. One way to disambiguate is to pad with 0s on the left, since `d` (and for all intents and purposes `Y`) are always the same amount of digits (2 and 4, respectively)

So, `$date=str_pad($date, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);` would turn
8312015 into 08312015, and then you could use `m` to format instead of `n`, and you should be OK from there. For months > 9, it would not change the input string, so it would be safe for all strings in that `ndY` format.

Comment: OP actually specified 'n' not 'm', but yeah, its not going to know whether he meant 8th month or 83rd month. OP should use 'm' for less ambiguity.

Comment: The question had "m" when I answered it... it was later edited to have "n".

Comment: @chiliNUT so the answer is ... You can't convert it? And the n is not telling that is only one digit if is less than 10?

Comment: @LeaTano see update, me and Octopus came up with roughly the same solution

Answer (score 1):

The answer is your input data must be normalized. I don't know what criteria you are using but I will assume that the last four characters will always be the year.

Now what I don't know is: does the day of the month always have to be two characters or could you get a date like '112015'? If so what should you do with '1112015'? Jan 11 or Nov 1?

Normalizing the data is very important.

Assuming that day of month is always two digits the simplest solution would be:

```
if ( strlen($date)<8 ) {
  $date = '0'.$date;
}
```

If both the date and the month might be one digit, then you are in trouble!